# Web site is not hitting web service after hosting in iis

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, iis

I have hosted my web site in IIS in my local machine. After being hosted the web site has stopped hitting the web service. Does anyone have an idea why this is happening.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that the page does not load at all, or that your break points are not hit/errors are not thrown in VS?

Comment: Did you configure the web service endpoints when you deployed the website?